# Open iframe video in fullscreen programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, webview, youtube, wkwebview

I open youtube video using iframe in webview. It shows default control buttons for video including fullscreen button. How can I call function of fullscreen button by myself? For example, I want go to fullscreen on landscape, but videos open in fullscreen only by tap on fullscreen button or while first loading. I need go to fullscreen while playing video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found function. There is `webkitEnterFullScreen` in webkit's  video tag: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlvideoelement

So all I need is to get video and execute function through javascript:

```
playerView.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('player').contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0].webkitEnterFullScreen()") { object, error in
       print(error)
}
```

Comment: For me this error happens: Optional(Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('player').contentDocument.getElementsByClassName'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=50, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL="" NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})

Comment: @Newsonic Seems that you have another html hierarchy. Try to search video player via source code of page in browser and then replace "document.getElementById('player').contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0]"

Comment: @Newsonic have you found a solution?

Comment: @ItayBrenner unfortunately nope

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using YTPlayer for YouTube Videos.
If not you can find the player here - [GithubLink](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

For YTPlayer, there's a parameter **playsinline.**
To always play fullscreen, you need to set the playsinline property to 0. Something like:

```
 let playerVars = [
    "playsinline" : 0
  ]
  player.loadWithVideo(id:movieURL, playerVars:playerVars)
```

Comment: yes, i use YTPlayer, but I have to reload video with this parameter for fullscreen. I need go to fullscreen while playing video (like user just tap fullscreen button)

Comment: When in portrait mode, save videos current time. On orientation change - pause the video, reload iFrame with new params and url, seek to video's last position.

Comment: Thank you, but there will be "lag" while I will reload video. I want same behaviour as well as just tap fullscreen button.

Comment: Follow this to get more details on your question [link](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/35)